# C#: Get first directory name of a relative path

Tags: c#, string, path, .net

How to get the first directory name in a relative path, given that they can be different accepted directory separators?

For example:

```
foo\bar\abc.txt -> foo
bar/foo/foobar -> bar
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Works with both forward and back slash

```
static string GetRootFolder(string path)
{
    while (true)
    {
        string temp = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
            break;
        path = temp;
    }
    return path;
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that's much more succint.

Comment: Don't think that will return the first directory as asked. But since it has been marked as the answer seems like it serves the purpose...in which case the question is incorrect. Please update

Comment: It will as long as the first directory doesn't start with any type of slash, or else it will just return the slash. For my use case in web urls, I simply trimmed the begginning slash.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as it will provide the same result as a call to Directory.GetDirectoryRoot().

Answer (score 12):

Seems like you could just use the [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method on the string, then grab the first element.
example (untested):

```
string str = "foo\bar\abc.txt";
string str2 = "bar/foo/foobar";


string[] items = str.split(new char[] {'/', '\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Console.WriteLine(items[0]); // prints "foo"

items = str2.split(new char[] {'/', '\'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
Console.WriteLine(items[0]); // prints "bar"
```

Comment: I tested a bunch of methods from this page and (at least for my data sets) this seemed to be one of the fastest but also most consistent results. I also substituted `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` in place of the characters.

Answer (score 5):

The most robust solution would be to use `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo`.  On a Windows NT-based system it should accept either forward or backslashes for separators.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetTopRelativeFolderName(@"foo\bar\abc.txt")); // prints 'foo'
        Console.WriteLine(GetTopRelativeFolderName("bar/foo/foobar")); // prints 'bar'
        Console.WriteLine(GetTopRelativeFolderName("C:/full/rooted/path")); // ** throws
    }

    private static string GetTopRelativeFolderName(string relativePath)
    {
        if (Path.IsPathRooted(relativePath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Path is not relative.", "relativePath");
        }

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(relativePath);
        DirectoryInfo workingDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(".");
        string topRelativeFolderName = string.Empty;
        DirectoryInfo current = fileInfo.Directory;
        bool found = false;
        while (!found)
        {
            if (current.FullName == workingDirectoryInfo.FullName)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                topRelativeFolderName = current.Name;
                current = current.Parent;
            }
        }

        return topRelativeFolderName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer provided by [Hasan Khan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36464/hasan-khan) ...

```
private static string GetRootFolder(string path)
{
    var root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);
    while (true)
    {
        var temp = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        if (temp != null && temp.Equals(root))
            break;
        path = temp;
    }
    return path;
}
```

This will give the the top level folder

Comment: Here's your answer. Use this method to turn: 
foo\bar\abc.txt -----> foo
bar/foo/foobar -----> bar

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question you ask, the following should work:

```
    public string GetTopLevelDir(string filePath)
    {
        string temp = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
        if(temp.Contains("\\"))
        {
            temp = temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf("\\"));
        }
        else if (temp.Contains("//"))
        {
            temp = temp.Substring(0, temp.IndexOf("\\"));
        }
        return temp;
    }
```

When passed `foo\bar\abc.txt` it will `foo` as wanted- same for the / case

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example in case your path if following format:

```
string path = "c:\foo\bar\abc.txt"; // or c:/foo/bar/abc.txt
string root = Path.GetPathRoot(path); // root == c:\
```

Comment: Is there _any_ OS that uses the `c:/foo/bar/abc.txt` convention?

Comment: You need to escape backslashes or use verbatim strings (`@" ... "`).

Comment: Escaping is necessary, I agree, else string is invalid. Regardless of conventions, example targets user's question and if "c:/foo/bar/abc.txt" supplied, code still works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
string str = "foo\bar\abc.txt";
string str2 = "bar/foo/foobar";

str.Replace("/", "\\").Split('\\').First(); // foo
str2.Replace("/", "\\").Split('\\').First(); // bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my example, with no memory footprint (without creating new strings in memory):

```
var slashIndex = relativePath.IndexOf('/');
var backslashIndex = relativePath.IndexOf('\\');
var firstSlashIndex = (slashIndex > 0) ? (slashIndex < backslashIndex ? slashIndex : (backslashIndex == -1) ? slashIndex : backslashIndex) : backslashIndex;
var rootDirectory = relativePath.Substring(0, firstSlashIndex);
```